# How to add left/right padding in Chart.js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart, padding

I'd like to add left and right padding to my Chart.js bar chart. I don't understand why only half of first and last bars are displayed:

[image]

I tried to play with `layout > padding` without success:

```
layout: {
  padding: {
    left: 20
  }
}
```

The code is available here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Maxbester/1ka2uh56/).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can provide padding to its container `<div class="col" style="padding:100px">
      <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
    </div>`

Comment: Actually what I really want is that the bars are the same width on my chart. Meaning not having 2017 and 2019 bars stuck to the border of the chart. This is why I asked how to add padding on the bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add. It will show equal width for first and last bar.

```
xAxes: [{
  offset: true,
}]
```